# How to portably force NAN * zero give zero in a particular expression without branching?

Tags: c++, performance, nan, branchless

In general, (quiet) NAN times zero should give NAN -- and it does.

However, in one particular performance-critical part of my code, I want zero times *anything* to be zero.

What's a fast way to do this in C++?

Comment: Have you actually measured to see if `(a==0.0 || b==0.0) ? 0 : a*b` is fast enough? Besides, you are aware that you need some pretty exceptional case to get exact zeroes from a computation, yes?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: Yes. I can assure you I know what I'm calculating and why this is the correct approach for doing so. I just need to know *how* to do it, that's all.

Comment: Just checking. What about the performance measurement – I don’t think you’ll be able to avoid branching, since the FPU has been wired for the NaN rules.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: Uhm what are you hoping that I've measured exactly? I've measured that my tight loop is the bottleneck in my code, but I quite obviously haven't compared it with a branchless version because I (obviously) don't know how to write a branchless version...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double mymult(double a, double b){
  double result[]={a*b,0.};
  return result[(a==0.)|(b==0.)];
}
```

should avoid branches: double check the generated assembly.

Not all `bool` calculations imply a branch.

Comment: Might not be a branch but it looks like it executes about 4 times as many instructions as a simple branched implementation when I look at the generated code. Which may or may not be better...

Comment: Given the costs of branch prediction fail - may well be worth it :) Of course, only testing can show

Comment: +1 for avoiding branches although it's not quite what I had in mind/not sure if it's actually faster. Thanks though.

Comment: @jcoder yes, more work is done.  There are other approaches that are less certain -- some compilers could actually turn `return (a==0.)?0.:(a*b);` into a branchless operation, and use of assembly that does a conditional register copy can similarly avoid PC branches.  The above is also symmetrical, and you implied you only needed one to be "possibly zero such that when multiplied by NaN it is still zero".

Comment: @Mehrdad Branchless code often does more things, but avoids pipeline stalls.  It is usually only best to use it when you either need consistent performance more than you need average performance, *or* where the condition can sometimes go either way.  The cost of a branch prediction fail is high, but the quality of even simple branch prediction algorithms is often shocking.

Comment: @Yakk: Yeah, you also had a good point there. I totally forgot that `x = cond ? x : y` can be a conditional-move instruction on some compilers... that's also another option. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it with arithmetic. You have to test for zero.

Comment: So basically there's no way to get rid of an NAN via computation once it's there?

Comment: I'd check if a call to isnan() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/ is "faster" for you

Comment: yeah but perhaps the isNan is a faster than the compare cycles wise, might be something to investigate